# How to fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'prices' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

I am making a tf2 trading bot. It gives me an error for data[baseName] being undefined but baseName will be a tf2 item and data is a list of all tf2 items.
part of data is:

```
{ 'Purity Fist':
   { defindex: [ 524 ],
     prices: { '0': [Object], '1': [Object], '6': [Object] } },
  'Black Rose':
   { defindex: [ 727 ], prices: { '0': [Object], '6': [Object] } },
  Bat:
   { defindex: [ 190, 0 ],
     prices:
      { '0': [Object],
        '3': [Object],
        '4': [Object],
        '6': [Object],
        '11': [Object] } },
  'Ellis\' Cap':
   { defindex: [ 263 ], prices: { '0': [Object], '6': [Object] } },
  Batsaber:
   { defindex: [ 30667 ],
     prices: { '0': [Object], '6': [Object], '11': [Object] } },
  'Prinny Machete':
   { defindex: [ 30758 ],
     prices: { '0': [Object], '1': [Object], '6': [Object] } },
  'Righteous Bison':
   { defindex: [ 442 ],
     prices:
      { '1': [Object], '6': [Object], '11': [Object], '14': [Object] } },
  'Sun-on-a-Stick':
   { defindex: [ 349 ],
     prices:
      { '1': [Object], '3': [Object], '6': [Object], '14': [Object] } },
  Grandmaster: { defindex: [ 1067 ], prices: { '1': [Object] } },
  'Mister Bubbles':
   { defindex: [ 1089 ], prices: { '1': [Object], '6': [Object] } },
  'Fan O\'War':
   { defindex: [ 355 ],
     prices:
      { '1': [Object],
        '3': [Object],
        '6': [Object],
        '11': [Object],
        '14': [Object] } },
  'Conniver\'s Kunai':
   { defindex: [ 356 ],
     prices:
      { '1': [Object],
        '3': [Object],
        '6': [Object],
        '11': [Object],
        '14': [Object] } },
```

```
var data = {

};
var currencies = {

};
requestify.get('https://backpack.tf/api/IGetPrices/v4?raw=1&since=0&key=5cf17c256780725011449df2')
    .then(function(response) {

    data = response.getBody().response.items;
    console.log(data);
  }
);
requestify.get('https://backpack.tf/api/IGetCurrencies/v1?key=5cf17c256780725011449df2')
  .then(function(response) {

      currencies = response.getBody().response.currencies;
  }
);

function toRef(keys, high) {
    if (high) {
        if (currencies.keys.price.value_high != undefined){
        return currencies.keys.price.value_high * keys
        } else {
            return currencies.keys.price.value * keys
        }
    } else {
        return currencies.keys.price.value * keys
    }
}
function getPrice(item, high) {
    var name = item.market_name;
    var quality = item.tags[0].name;
    var baseName = name.replace(quality + " ", "");
    var qualityId = itemQualities[quality];
    var isCraftable = true;
    for (i = 0;i < item.descriptions.length;i++) {
        if (item.descriptions[i].value == '( Not Usable in Crafting )') {
            isCraftable = false;
        }
    }

    if (high) {
        if (data[baseName].prices[qualityId.toString()].Tradable[isCraftable.toString()][0].currency == "keys") {
            return toRef(data[baseName]['prices'][qualityId.toString()]['Tradable'][isCraftable.toString()][0].value_high, true);
        } else {
            return data[baseName].prices[qualityId.toString()].Tradable[isCraftable.toString()][0].value_high;
        }
    } else {
        if (data[baseName].prices[qualityId.toString()].Tradable[isCraftable.toString()][0].currency == "keys") {   
            return toRef(data[baseName].prices[qualityId.toString()].Tradable[isCraftable.toString()][0].value, false);
        } else {
            return data[baseName].prices[qualityId.toString()].Tradable[isCraftable.toString()][0].value;
        }
    }

}
```

It should return the value of data[baseName].prices[qualityId.toString()].Tradable[isCraftable.toString()][0].value but it errors

Comment: `data[baseName]` is `undefined`.

Comment: @VLAZ That's the issue

Comment: Yes but you are the best person to trace why that is the case. What is the value of `baseName`? What are the keys available in `data`? There is obviously a mismatch. It's weird to expect outside people to be able to tell you what the mismatch is instead of doing basic debugging.

Comment: @VLAZ It is erroring before it is even called so baseName is not yet defined

Comment: Then...that's your problem? Although the error message suggests that `data[baseName].prices` in `if (data[baseName].prices[qualityId.toString()].Tradable[isCraftable.toString()][0].currency == "keys") {` is what causes the issue and that is after `var baseName = name.replace(quality + " ", "");` has executed. If it errors before that, then you've provided us with the wrong error message or haven't provided us with the code that actually throws the error.

Comment: @VLAZ it is defined when it is called but before that, it is null, not undefined. Sorry for the mismatch